# VBA Advanced Filter works in local Workbook, but not when placed in Personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, xlsb, vba

This code works in the local Workbook perfectly, but I can not figure out how (and I tried a couple of suggestions here on S.O.F.) to get it to work in the Personal.xlsb file. Any help is much appreciated.
'This macro works locally - need to get it to work at the Personal.xlsb level

```
'This macro works locally - need to get it to work at the Personal.xlsb level
Sub AdvLookupVals()

   Dim colA_Range As Range
   Dim rngLookupRange As Range
   Dim rngFoundRange As Range
   Dim wb As Workbook

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

   'when you do this, Lookup.xls becomes active and sets the range
   Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Lists\Resource_Lookup.xlsx", True, True) ' open the source workbook, read only
   Set rngLookupRange = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A656")

   'Makes target workbook active again
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

   'Set rngFoundRange = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A653")
   'rngFoundRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= '_   'hoping this would make the macro work in Personal.xlsb

       Range("A1:A653").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        rngLookupRange, Unique:=False                                               'rngLookupRange gets the criteria from above. .filters by name.

   'releases resources back to the system and close the other workbook
   Set rngLookupRange = Nothing
   wb.Close False ' close the source workbook without saving any changes
   Set wb = Nothing ' frees memory

 End Sub
```

Comment: It would help to explain exactly what your code is *supposed* to do.  Personal.xls(b) is typically a hidden workbook, so it's not clear why you're Activating it?

Comment: I store my most used macros there, so they are available at Excel startup and can work on non-macro enabled workbooks.  This code activates a workbook with a list of resource names for lookup.  It is not activating the personal.xlsb file.

Comment: it is this piece of of code for the advanced filter that is not working from the personal.xlsb:  
       Range("A1:A653").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        rngLookupRange, Unique:=False

Comment: If the code is running in Personal.xlsb then `ThisWorkbook` is Personal.xlsb.

Comment: That makes sense, Tim.  Any suggestions to correct?

Comment: Please see my first comment - need to know step by step what it's *supposed* to do.

Comment: (1 of 2) Purpose: retrieve list of names from workbook titled "Resource_Lookup.xlsx", on "sheet 1" Range A1:A656.  Then it uses that list as the criteria to set the Advanced filter on the first and fith columns on "sheet 1" of the active macro-enabled Workbook.  It does this all perfectly.

Comment: (2 of 2) I would like to house this macro, with my other handy macros in the personal.xlsb file so that it will be available at Excel startup instead of having to copy the report I need to quickly sort into the macro-enabled file.  It is when I move the code from the macro-enabled file to the personal.xlsb file I get the runtime error.  All, my other macrosused to modify this same report are run from the personal.xlsb file.  This code does not at this point.  This is where I am asking for insight as to why and how to fix it to run out of the Personal.xlsb file.  Thank you.